# positioning multiple background images

Tags: html, css, background-image

This is my code.I want to move that yellow circle to right (about 25px) .how can I give that style to the second image only.

```css
.img_home
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle1.png),url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle2.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="img_home"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
.img_home
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 1000px;
    background: url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle1.png) 25px top no-repeat,url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_home"></div>
```

Comment: Great!! @user94

Answer (score 2):

simply add `background-position: 25px 0px, 0px 0px;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.img_home
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 1000px;
    background: url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle1.png) 25px 0 no-repeat,url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_home">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with setuping parameters with `background`:

`background:` `url` `repeat` `posX` `posY`

```css
.img_home
{
    height: 1000px;
    background: url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle1.png) no-repeat,url(http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Circle2.png) no-repeat 200px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_home"></div>
```